# Singleton with AlertDialog make my android application crashing

Tags: java, android, singleton

I am new in android and I am trying to build an android application and I use singleton pattern to show alert dialog but when I run application it crashed.
I tried to remove singleton it worked correctly.
this is my code
***LoadingDialog.java***

```
public class LoadingDialog {
    private Activity activity;
    private AlertDialog dialog;

    private static LoadingDialog loadDialog;

    public LoadingDialog(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public static synchronized LoadingDialog getInstance(Activity activity) {
        if (loadDialog == null) {
            loadDialog = new LoadingDialog(activity);
        }
        return loadDialog;
    }

    public void startDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading,null));
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    public void closeDialog() {
        dialog. Dismiss();
    }
}
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
private ActivityMainBinding binding;
private LoadingDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        dialog = LoadingDialog.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
        binding.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.startDialog();
            }
        });
```

it gives me this error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mkandeel.gmarek, PID: 20063
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@4723521 is not valid; is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:678)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:316)
at com.mkandeel.gmarek.LoadingDialog.startDialog(LoadingDialog.java:30)
at com.mkandeel.gmarek.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1211)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

so what is the problem with my code ?
Thanks in advance.

I tried to use class without singleton by making my constrictor public and it work correctly

Comment: Please add complete stack trace, not able to see the error.

Comment: I already added it but I edit the format to display error

Answer (score 0):

I think the wrong is your activity is null when you call to startDialog():

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
dialog = LoadingDialog.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
binding.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    dialog.startDialog();
    }
});
```

Because when you call getInstance you create the instance using the activity by param, but the activity in the scope of LoadingDialog is not initialized, so it is null.  Then, when you call the startDialog(), the activity in the Builder is null:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
```

So, a solution could be:

```
 public static synchronized LoadingDialog getInstance(Activity activity) {
        if (loadDialog == null && this.activity == activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
            loadDialog = new LoadingDialog(activity);
        }
        return loadDialog;
    }
```

I am checking the activity instance too because if you call the singleton class from another activity, then it could cause a memory leak.

Anyway, IMO It is not necessary a singleton class to show a dialog and the `synchronized` keyword neither

Comment: I tried that but I get the same error

Comment: mmm... the stracktrace said that the activity state is not the appropiate (destroyed, rotation, etc), so you could try to verify the state before the startDialog: !(this.isDestroyed || this.isFinishing)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you are showing the dialog for a context/activity that no longer exists.

Before calling .show() check that activity/context is not finishing

```
public void startDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading,null));
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    dialog = builder.create();
    
    if (!activity.isFinishing()){
         dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, now application didn't crash but dialog doesn't appear it appears in only one activity